# how to assign a vector in vhdl to zero?

Tags: vhdl

i have a vector temp in vhdl and i want the vector to be equal to zero if the vector reached the  maximum count_limit .. the vector size is generic .. how can i do something like this ?

```
GENERIC ( SIZE      : INTEGER := 8);
constant count_limit : std_logic_vector(SIZE - 1 downto 0) := ( others => '1'); -- max value 
signal temp: std_logic_vector(SIZE - 1 downto 0);

-- here i want to check if temp was equal to the max vaue then i want temp to be zero
-- here is what i did but thats not correct !

temp <= ( others => '0');
```

Comment: "here is what i did but thats not correct !" That **is** the way to set a vector to zero. But the *location* of `temp <= ( others => '0'); ` is wrong. You need to put it inside the `begin..end` of an architecture.

Comment: We need an MCVE to tell you what is exactly wrong. From the code you posted, it is impossible to tell where your architecture begins or if you have some kind of process for `temp`.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)? Example of wise advice you can find there: "_Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems like what you want to do is this:

```
--inside declaration part of the architecture
signal temp : unsigned(SIZE-1 downto 0);
constant count_limit : unsigned(SIZE - 1 downto 0) := ( others => '1');

--in the body
clocked_count: process(clk) begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if temp < count_limit then
      temp <= temp +1;
    else temp <= (others => '0');
    end if;
   end if;
 end
```

The above process will increment temp's value every clock cycle as long as it's saved(last) value is smaller than count_limit. When count_limit is reached, temp is zeroed. The comparisons work only if you declare the signals as unsigned because then there is no ambiguity about what the bit vector represents.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.